# Vault Software for windows using batch file, HTML , CSS and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, windows, batch-file

I am a web developer and i am really curious about desktop applications.I just started little tasks with `batch`files. I developed a vault app to protect folders using `batch code`, `HTML` , `CSS`  and  `javascript`.

**Algorithm**

1. Run the batch file
2. `HTML` and `CSS` will do the UI stuffs like styles
3. if user click on the lock button , run the lock.bat file using `javascript`

   lock.bat

   ```
   title on.txt 
   ren MyFolder "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}"
   attrib +h +s "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}"
   ```

   which hide the folder "MyFolder" (not a proper way and not secure)
4. Display locked message and unlock button
5. if user click on the unlock button , ask for password. `Javascript` will    verify the password.
6. if the password is correct it will run the unlock.bat file

   unlock.bat

   ```
   attrib -h -s "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}"
   ren "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}" MyFolder
   del "status.txt"
   START MyFolder
   ```

   7. if password is wrong `javascript` will display an error message

**Note** : When user do the Lock action i am creating a textfile (status.txt), and delete the same text file when user do the unlock action.
everytime i check the existance of the this file (status.txt). If the file exist then system understands the folder is "locked".

I would like to implement this in a proper way using web languages without using any frameworks like app.js. Any body help me to any alternative ways to do this the folder.

Comment: This site is for helping with specific programming issues in the code you provide, it is not a platform for bouncing ideas around for the design or implementation of new projects.

Comment: yes. but my question is , is there any other ways to achieve step.3 and step.6 ?

Comment: You have two pieces of batch code, `3.` and `6.`, neither of which you've reported as disfunctional, your question therefore remains off-topic. This site is not [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions), it is not the appropriate location for your question more especially because you're looking for opinion, and questions of that type are also off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

Im sorry but this can't be done from JS, HTML or also jQuery. This would be a HUGE security issue: If anyone could just run a batch script, that could absolutely damage your system with its commands. So there is not any way to run a batch script trough a website. You could still try to run a completely-batch file, without any UI but at least your code could work, try:

```
if not exist "%systemdrive%\Windows\password.txt" goto passSet
(
set /p "pass="
)<%systemdrive%\Windows\password.txt
goto passSetted
:passSet
set /p "pass=Please insert the password you want to use. (user-input) "
echo %pass%>%systemdrive%\Windows\password.txt
goto passSetted
:passSetted
if exist %cd%\MyFolder (goto lock) else (goto unlock)
:lock
title on.txt 
ren MyFolder "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}"
attrib +h +s "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}"
echo Folder Locked.
pause >nul
exit /b
:unlock
set /p "passtry=Please insert the password to unlock the file. "
if not "%passtry%"=="%pass%" goto fail
attrib -h -s "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}"
ren "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}" MyFolder
del "status.txt"
START MyFolder
echo Folder Unlocked.
pause >nul
exit /b
:fail
echo You inserted the wrong password.
pause >nul
exit /b
```

You can use `goto unlock` instead of `exit /b` to get the user another attempt to insert the password.